# Python serial readline using ord()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am reading serial port in raspberry pi then convert result value to hex but have ord() error. Code was run ok in the past but raspberry must be replaced and now code fail

Serial give me a value like this:

Empty= b''

NO empty = b'\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd'

This is part of my code when failing:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os, sys
import serial
import time
from datetime import datetime

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0',19200, timeout = 5)

# listen for the input, exit if nothing received in timeout period
while True:
    line = ser.readline()

   if len(line) == 0:
        print("Time out! Exit.\n")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        for card_code in line:
            card_hex=hex(ord(card_code))

            if len(card_hex) == 3:
                card_result=card_result+'0'+card_hex[2:]+' '
            else:
                card_result=card_redult+card_hex[2:]+' '

        card_result=card_result.upper()
        card_result=card_result.strip()
        card_result=card_result.replace(' ',':')
        card_result=card_result[0:23]

        #print(card_result) must be something like this: "07:00:EE:00:EE:C8:A4:37"
```

If serial value is no empty i need convert it to hex and proccess but have error from ord() "expecting string but is int"

Nevertheless if assign value directly to a variable "line" to test and run ord(line) is ok:

```
line = "b'\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\..."

....

for card_code in line:
    print(ord(card_code))     

    card_hex=hex(ord(card_code))

    print(card_hex)
....

Result:
98
0x62
39
0x27
176
0xb0
...

card_result = 62:27:B0:A1:FD:B0:A1:FD #ord(line) work fine
```

Updating more details from print line = ser.readline() :

```
line TYPE:  <class 'bytes'>
line when empty: b''

line with content: b'\xb0y\xfd\xb0y\xfd\xb0y\xfd\xb0y\xfd\xb0y\xfd\xb0y\xfd\xb0y\xfd\xb0y\xfd\xb0y\xfd\xb0y\xfd\xb0y\xfd\xb0y\xfd\xb0y\xfd\xb0y\xfd\xb0y\xfd\xb0y\xfd\xb0y\xfd\xb0y\xfd\xb0y\xfd\xb0y\xfd\xb0y\xfd\xb0y\xfd\xb0y\xfd\xb0y\xfd\xb0y\xfd\xb0y\xfd\xb0y\xfd\xb0y\xfd\xb0y\xfd\xb0y\xfd\xb0y\xfd\xb0y\xfd\xb0y\xfd\xb0y\xfd\xb0y\xfd\xb0y\xfd\xb0y\xfd\xb0y\xfd\xb0y\xfd\xb0y\xfd\xb0y\xfd\xb0y\xfd\xb0y\xfd\xb0y\xfd\xb0y\xfd\xb0y\xfd\xb0y\xfd\xb0y\xfd'
```

What is different?

Is serial result a string value? What is wrong?

Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Python 2.7.16
Python 3.7.3

Comment: If you want to know the type, you can check the `type`. If the error is just `ord` needing string, but is int, you can do something like this: `[ord(char) for char in str(1234)]`, where `1234` is your number.

Comment: `ord()` does not support `bytes` or `bytearray` characters in some versions of Python3.  what version are *you* using?

Comment: it is a bytearray. Python 3.7.3 in Raspbian

Comment: @Richardmax please update your code showing the error you get when using `card_hex=hex(card_code)` directly (without 'ord' function) and printing the `type` and contents of the variable `line` when you get the error.

Comment: @tglaria I changed to run script with `sudo /usr/bin/python3 file.py` and work fine with `card_hex=hex(card_code)` reading from serial port. I'm newie in Python. thanks you very much!

Comment: @Richardmax the "sudo" shouldn't be a reason for the script to not to work, so maybe you just got lucky but you'll get the same error in the future. I do beleive you should try to find the source of the error.

Comment: sorry @tglaria. is not about "sudo". is about python version. before i used /usr/bin/python script.py now use /usr/bin/python3 script.py and work fine :)

Comment: @richardmax I get it, well you never said which version of python you were using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Python 3, pyserial output is a byte, not a string. So, each `card_code in line` is an integer. 
Just skip the `ord` part:

```
card_result = ''
for card_code in line:
    # card_hex=hex(ord(card_code))
    card_hex=hex(card_code)        # <---------- Change this part

    if len(card_hex) == 3:
        card_result=card_result+'0'+card_hex[2:]+' '
    else:
        card_result=card_result+card_hex[2:]+' '

card_result=card_result.upper()
card_result=card_result.strip()
card_result=card_result.replace(' ',':')
card_result=card_result[0:23]    
print(card_result) # My output was: B0:A1:FD:B0:A1:FD:B0:A1
```

I tested it with the data you wrote:

```
line = b'\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd'
```

EDIT:

Answering your questions:
`What is different?`
Probably you were using python2 previously.

`Is serial result a string value? What is wrong?`
Nope, the output is `bytes`.
When you use `for c in bytes_type:` then you're picking each byte (instead of a character when it was a string).

Comment: Hi @tglaria. thanks for the answer. i try to suggestion but have error: card_hex=hex(card_code) TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: That would mean that your `line` is not of `bytes type` but ¿an array?. Please print print/store your `line` variable and its type to see what could it be. I just tested the input you wrote as an example.

Comment: When you tet with `line = "b'\xb0\xa1\xfd\xb0\xa1\xfd\..."`, you're storing a string in the variable `line` (see the double quote before the b). If I store that varibale as bytes, I get an error with your code.

Comment: Understood. Thank you very much